# Adding two byte arrays which represent unsigned numbers together fails to add last carry in c

Tags: arrays, c, bit-manipulation, addition, bigint

I have been writing a big numbers library for practice reasons in C and the addition operation is causing me some issues. It works normally but ignores the carry at the end and the result is incorrect.

I have been trying to write a big number library in c and here is the code so far for the addition operation. Code so far:

The `BIG_INT` type is a `typedef` for a `unsigned char` array of 8 bytes.
8 bytes is used for testing, it will be like 512 bytes later.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BIG_INT_SIZE 8
typedef unsigned char BIG_INT[BIG_INT_SIZE];

int add_big_int(BIG_INT *left, size_t right)
{
    if (!right)
        return 0;

    char buffer[sizeof(size_t)];
    memcpy(buffer, &right, sizeof(size_t));

    unsigned int carry = 0;
    for (int64_t i = BIG_INT_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        unsigned int sum = (*left[i] & 0xff) + (buffer[i] & 0xff) + carry;
        *left[i] = sum;
        carry = sum >> 8;
    }

    printf("carry: %u\n", carry);
    return 0;
}

int main() 
{
    BIG_INT big = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    add_big_int(&big, 255);
    return 0;
}
```

When adding numbers like `256 + 1 = 257`, the byte array is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]` (reverse order), however when adding `255 + 1 = 256`, the byte array is `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]` instead of the expected `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]` and the carry variable is set to `1`.

Comment: What do you think that `sizeof(left)` does? I think you should introduce the idea of a specific length, not use the `sizeof` various C types. If your bigint has 8 elements: say so.

Comment: When you add two integers, you can get a result with one more significant digit (in whatever base) than the addend with the greater magnitude.  You do not appear to provide for that.

Comment: You have primed yourself for trouble on implementations where `char` is signed, which are common.  You probably want to do your addition with **unsigned** (big) digits, whether your bigint representation uses sign / magnitude or two's complement representation for negative numbers, or especially if it does not support negative numbers at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  OP already gives a MVCE, what more are you asking?

Comment: @BadZen: There is no MVCE in the question. The code there does not compile cleanly. It is missing three `#include` directives, a definition of the macro `ZERO_MEMORY`, and a definition of the type `BIG_INT`. And, as noted above, there does not appear to be a definition of `BIG_INT` that would make the code work at all.

Comment: @block103 the `ZERO_MEMORY` isn't necessary because you immediately use `memcpy()` to fill the buffer.

Comment: Re the update's `typedef unsigned char BIG_INT[8];` you absolutely need that `8` to be a central definition to everything else that is going on, not an isolated magic number.

Comment: OK but please don't develop the code in the post. Such as introducing `#define BIG_INT_SIZE 8` which wasn't there before.

Comment: Eventually you'll want to replace `unsigned char` by `unsigned long` or whatever is the "native" word size for your machine.  A 32/64-bit add is usually just as fast as an 8-bit, and you only need 1/4 or 1/8 as many of them.  (Though you will then need to compute the carry a little differently.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is disorganized, and some organization will help fix it.

Look at this loop: `for (int64_t i = BIG_INT_SIZE - 1; i >= 0; --i)`. That iterates through `BIG_INT_SIZE` elements, using `left[i]` and `buffer[i]`. How many elements are in `buffer`?

`buffer` is declared `char buffer[sizeof(size_t)];`, so, if `sizeof(size_t)` is different from `BIG_INT_SIZE`, the loop is massively broken. You either need `buffer` and `left` to have the same number of elements or you need code in the loop to handle disparate sizes.

Let’s make them the same size, using `char buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE];`.

Next, compare these two declarations:

```
typedef unsigned char BIG_INT[BIG_INT_SIZE];
```

```
   char buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE];
```

What is different? One uses `unsigned char`, and the other uses `char`. The C standard does not say whether `char` is signed or unsigned. When you put 255 in signed `char`, it is likely to take on the value −1, although this is implementation-defined. You want `unsigned char`:

```
   unsigned char buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE];
```

Next, you have `memcpy(buffer, &right, sizeof(size_t));`, but we need to account for the change in how the size of `buffer` is set. Also, `memcpy` copies the bytes in whatever order they are in memory, but you want the low bytes at higher addresses, judging from your other code. So what you can do is:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof right; ++i)
   {
       buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE - 1 - i] = right & 0xff;
       right >>= 8;
   }
   for (int i = sizeof right; i < BIG_INT_SIZE; ++i)
       buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE - 1 - i] = 0;
```

The first loops puts the low-value byte of `right` into the high-address element of `buffer` and then shifts the bytes of `right` right. The second loop fills in any further elements of `buffer` with zeros.

A potential hazard here is that `right` is larger than `buffer`, which would make the first loop overrun the buffer. We can guard against that with:

```
    _Static_assert(sizeof right <= sizeof buffer, "right is too big for buffer");
```

I used `& 0xff` above, mimicking your existing code. Often, people would design for an eight-bit byte, in which case the `& 0xff` is unnecessary; the assignment could be just `buffer[BIG_INT_SIZE - 1 - i] = right;`, and the automatic conversion of `right` to `unsigned char` will effectively remove higher bits. If you make that change, you may want to insert a `_Static_assert` that `CHAR_BIT` is eight. `CHAR_BIT` is defined in `<limits.h>`.

Next, look at `unsigned int sum = (*left[i] & 0xff) + (buffer[i] & 0xff) + carry;`. Array subscripting has higher precedence than pointer dereferencing, so `*left[i]` is `*(left[i])`, not `(*left)[i]`. `left` is a pointer to `BIG_INT`, and just one `BIG_INT` is passed, so you cannot use `left[i]` with `i` being non-zero. You need `(*left)` to get the `BIG_INT` and then `[i]` to select an element from it, so you want `unsigned int sum = ((*left)[i] & 0xff) + (buffer[i] & 0xff) + carry;`.

Similarly, `*left[i] = sum;` should be `(*left)[i] = sum;`.

With those changes made, your code will get the correct answer for the case you show. However, you should consider other design aspects, including:

- Do you want to define `BIG_INT` as an array? It may be safer as a structure containing an array. This would have caught the `*left[i]` error earlier?
- Why is the type of `right` `size_t`? `size_t` has a connotation that it is used with object sizes, not arbitrary arithmetic values that might be used with big-integer types. Do you want to use a signed type for it?
- Why does the loop use `int64_t` for `i`? That is a fixed-width type. You might want a type like `ptrdiff_t`, which is suitable for indexing arrays (it is signed, so it can be used with an `i >= 0` test, and it is a type designed to adjust its width to the target platform.)
- What will you do when the final `carry` is non-zero?
- Will `add_big_int` always return zero, or do you have some future plan for it?

Comment: 1. After your answer I redid the code so that it used a struct instead of a fixed sized array which allows me to make a big integer with any size.

2. I only intended to use unsigned values

3. I didnt know about ptrdiff_t

4. Shift the bits

5. add_big_int returns 0 if successful, and 1 if failure (if the pointer provided is null) and maybe return 2 if an overflow happens.

Answer (score 0):

For starters the first parameter of the function is a pointer

```
int add_big_int(BIG_INT* left, size_t right)
                ^^^^^^^^
```

If `BIG_INT` is defined like

```
typedef unsigned char BIG_INT[8];
```

then it means that the parameter has the type `char ( * )[8]`.

There is no great sense to pass the array through a pointer to it. It is enough to declare the function like

```
int add_big_int(BIG_INT left, size_t right)
```

and call it like

```
add_big_int(big, 255);
```

The function always returns `0` that is not informative for the user of the function. Either the function should return meaningful values or its return type should be `void`.

Using the type `size_t` as for example

```
char buffer[sizeof(size_t)];
```

only confuses readers of the code.

Insetad you could use expression `sizeof( BIG_INT )` provided that the array `BIG_INT` is large enough to store values of the type `size_t`.

The used expression `*left[i]` invokes undefined behavior. Instead you have to use expression `( *left )[i]`. But in any case using expressions with the bitwise AND operator like

```
(buffer[i] & 0xff)
```

has no effect because you have arrays with the element type `unsigned char`.

In general you should use a dynamically allocated array enclosed in a structure due to using the carry flag because there can be an overflow.